# Use WPF ResourceDictionary in .NetStandard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, resourcedictionary

I have some styles and custom controls that I wrote in WPF and in ResourceDictionary.
Now I want to use these styles in xamarin but I realized that the library should be based on .NetStandard to be installed on xamarin.

But now I see that the ResourceDictionary does not exist.

How do I upgrade my code for WPF to xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately**, Xamarin can not use WPF'S ResourceDictionary.

You can [Create and Consume a Xamarin's ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#creating-and-consuming-a-resourcedictionary) as follow.

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="PageBackgroundColor">Yellow</Color>
            <Color x:Key="HeadingTextColor">Black</Color>
            <Color x:Key="NormalTextColor">Blue</Color>
            <Style x:Key="LabelPageHeadingStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeadingTextColor}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```